# Inequality for $s\in(1,2)$, $t>1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $s\in(1,2)$, $t>1$ and $t-1>\frac{4}{q}t(s-1)$ where $q\in(0,p-1)$ for $p\geq 2$. Then does the following inequality hold:
$$
(s-1)<c(p)t^q-d(p)s^p
$$
for some constants $c(p),d(p)$ depending on $p$.
In fact it hods when $p=2$. The proof goes as follows:
By the mean value theorem there exists $\eta\in(1,t)$ such that $t^q-1=q\eta^{q-1}(t-1)$. Then
$$
\frac{(s+2)(s-1)}{t-1}\leq\frac{q(s+2)}{4t}\leq\frac{q}{t}\leq\frac{q}{t^{1-q}}\leq q\eta^{q-1}=\frac{t^q-1}{t-1}.$$ Therefore, we have
$$
(s+2)(s-1)\leq t^q-1,
$$
which gives
$$
s-1\leq t^q-s^2.
$$
Hence the proof follows. So $c(p)=d(p)=1$ here.
Any hint when $p>2$?
Thanks in advance.
$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $q \in (0, p-1)$ for $p \geq 2$?. Otherwise, there's no reason for you to prove this for $p=2$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $s \in (1,2)$ , $t>1$ &  $t-1 > \frac{4t(s-1)}{q}$, where $q \in (0, p-1)$ for all $p> 2$. We proceed by way of contradiction. Assume the inequality doesn't hold for any constants $c(p)$ & $d(p)$.

Let $c(p) = d(p) = p$ so that $s-1 \geq p(t^q - s^p)$. Since $s>1 $ , $p> 2$ & $t>1$ we've,

$2-1>s-1 \geq p(t^q - s^p)> 2(1- s^p)$. So, $1> 2(1- s^p)$. This gives, $s^p>1/2$ for all $p>2$ & $s \in (1,2)$. But, this is a contradiction since we can choose $s$ & $p$ such that $s^p < 1/2$.

Thus, the inequality holds for $p>2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am little confused since how can you choose $t=9$?

Comment: And also if your argument is correct, then the result should be true, since your argument is by contradiction.

Comment: I think may be this argument be useful to get a conclusion. But still not a complete solution. Suppose by contradiction, the result does not hold. Then there exists $s\in(1,2)$, $t_0>1$ and $q_0\in(0,p-1)$ such that for all $c(p)$ one has $s_0-1\geq c(p)t_0^{q}-d(p)s_0^p$ under the given condition $t_0-1>\frac{4}{q_0}t_0(s_0-1)$. Since $c(p),d(p)$ is arbitrary, we may assume that $c(p)=d(p)$. If $t_0^{q_0}-s_{0}^p>0$, then we can choose $c(p)$ large enough to get a contradiction. Else if $t_0^{q_0}-s_{0}^p<0$, then the above inequalities simultaneaously cannot hold, but unable to prove it.

Comment: I chose $t=9$ & $s=5/4$ so that $t-1> 4(s-1)t/q$ holds & at the same time, this choice of $t$ gives a contradiction.

Comment: But if you are going by contradiction, then there exists some $t,s$ such that the above inequality holds. But how can you choose exactly such an $s$ and $t$. Also since the statement is true for $p=2$ as proof is written above.

Comment: well you've proved that the inequality holds (when $p=2$) for ANY $s\in (1,2)$ & ANY $t>1$ s.t blah blah...So, there exist such $c(p)$ & $d(p)$ (depending on $p$) that fit in the inequality. All I've proved is the result doesn't hold for ALL $p>2$ by finding some $s$ & $t$ that would violate the inequality

Comment: But how can you choose $c(p)=3$? In fact we need the inequality for some $c(p)$.

Comment: @Mathlover true.I made a mess of it. I edited my previous answer. check it out.

Comment: If you go by contradiction, then you cannot choose $s$ and $t$. In fact such $s$ and $t$ exists. Anyway $s^p>\frac{1}{2}$ is not a contradiction, since $s>1$ so $s^p>1>\frac{1}{2}$. @SL_MathGuy

Comment: Is it possible to prove that $s^q-t^p$ always positive under the given hypothesis? Then the result will hold as I have written the argument in the comment.

Comment: Also in the proof you did not use the hypothesis $t-1>\frac{4t}{q}(s-1)$. May be using this condition something can be deduced. Thanks. @SL_MathGyu